# How do I make Sass work?

Tags: sass

This might be a dumb question but I stumbled upon this awesome CodePen that I wanted to adjust and use. I launched a quick demo on my own server but it didn't work. Then I realized that next to CodePen it said SCSS, which I googled. I sorta get it but I don't know how to make this particular code work.

The html:

```html
<body>


    <div id="paper"> </div>
    <div class="wrap">
            <a class="two" href="http://db.tt/vkXgwK2P">
                <img class="round" src="http://db.tt/vkXgwK2P" alt="">
            </a>
            <a class="three" href="http://db.tt/Lrtnc768">
                <img class="round" src="http://db.tt/Lrtnc768" alt="">
            </a>
            <a class="one" href="http://db.tt/CSVy5HNR">
                <img  class="round"  src="http://db.tt/CSVy5HNR" alt="">
            </a>


            <figure>
                <img src="http://db.tt/FveX1nYo" alt="">
            </figure>
    </div>
```

The SCSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#paper {
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #303535; 
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px white;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
  background: #fff;

  a {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    .round {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 180px;
      height: 180px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px white;
    }
  }
  figure img {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: top 0.4s ease-out;
    position: absolute;     
    top: 200px;
    left: 77px;
  }
  .two {
    margin: 0;

    -webkit-transition: top 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: top 0.4s ease-out;  
    opacity: 0.8;   
    top: 0; 
  }
  .three {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: top 0.4s ease-out;      
    opacity: 0.8;
    top: 0;
  }
  &:hover .one {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  & a.one:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  :hover .two {
    top: 300px;
  }
  & a.two:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  &:hover .three {
    top: 150px;
  }
  & a.three:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  &:hover figure img {
    top: 500px;     
  }
}
```

There is also an example of what I'm trying to achieve at CodePen: http://codepen.io/CoffeeCupDrummer/pen/FqChm

I thought maybe the problem was in my link syntax so I changed it to look like this, but that didn't work either. I tried style.css then switched to style.scss in hopes of fixing it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.scss">
```

So my question is whats so different about SCSS and why can't I get it to work when it works just fine on CodePen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The matter is that you have to compile your SCSS into CSS. There are no browsers that support Sass:  you must compile it first with a Sass compiler and then link to the compiled CSS.  Codepen does that for you automatically.

## How to compile Sass

There are two common ways to compile Sass, both of them automatically compile your code whenever you make changes to it:

- Use the `sass` command line tool that comes with the [Sass gem](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html)
- Use some GUI tool like [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) or [Compass.App](http://compass.handlino.com/)

It's worth noting that Codepen compiles using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/), which I recommend using rather than the vanilla Sass compiler.  In addition to providing extra functions and a library of useful mixins, it uses a configuration file (`config.rb`) file so that you just have to run the `compass watch` command to compile on the fly as you code.

This sounds like a bit of a hassle, but it's worth your while. Compass leverages Sass to a whole new level with it's library of mixins and an ecosystem of Compass extensions: [grid systems](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity), [tools to make your site responsive](https://github.com/lolmaus/breakpoint-slicer), handy [shortcuts](http://jaredhardy.com/sassy-buttons/) and [tools](https://github.com/Team-Sass/toolkit).