# how to change the scss?

Tags: html, sass, bourbon

I am learning scss and found this sample:

```
https://github.com/jasonsanjose/bourbon-example
```

When I try to change the app.scss file making the color of the button green it does not change from red:

```
@import "../bower_components/bourbon";
@import "partial";

* {
    font-family: $helvetica;
}

button {
    @include button(pill, green);
}
```

How can I run the index.html page successfully?

Comment: Have you refreshed the browser  , clear cache and run again and check

Comment: yes still not working, what do I need to install for scss?

Comment: Did you compile scss files to css?

Comment: how do you do this without ruby?

Comment: I think that is not possible without ruby and sass. You have to install ruby and sass.

Comment: I installed sass, but it is still not working?

Comment: Ok, so did you *run* Sass (hint: read the documentation if you don't know how)?  "Not working" is *never* an acceptable description of the problem.  Was there an error?  What was the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make Sass Work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207581/how-do-i-make-sass-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile the SASS file to CSS file to get it worked properly using Ruby..
If you don't wanna use Ruby then you need to download third party applications to compile the code for you..Here are some of the apps you can use:

CodeKit (Paid)
Mixture (Free)  
http://mixture.io/
Prepros (Paid/Also available for one month trial)   
 https://prepros.io/

Comment: How can I compile the sass files in the project?

Comment: I am currently using Prepros for Less/SASS files compilation..once you installed Prepros you need to import the project or Sass file folder to it..then from the list select the sass file you want to compile .. after selecting the file you'll see a panel asking for OUTPUT PATH..set output path and press Compile..it will create CSS file in output directory..P.S. for compiling multiple SASS files.. you need to create one common SASS file and import rest of the files in this and compile the same..Thanks

Comment: for command line compilation using Ruby please follow the steps provided at :  http://sass-lang.com/install

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you should compile your SCSS code into CSS first.

To learn and understand Sass you can use SassMeister to compile your SCSS code: http://sassmeister.com/gist/59b634f15fb98d630173

This file compiles the following SCSS code:

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
* {
    font-family: $helvetica;
}

button {
    @include button(pill, green);
}
```

The above should compile into CSS code as follows:

```
* {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid #082c08;
  border-color: #082c08 #021303 black;
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #04a301, 0 1px 2px 0 #b3b3b3;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: green;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, green), color-stop(100%, #004d0a));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(green, #004d0a);
  background-image: linear-gradient(green, #004d0a);
  padding: 5px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #052f08;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
button:hover:not(:disabled) {
  border: 1px solid #021302;
  border-color: #021302 black black;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #018f01;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #006900;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #006900), color-stop(100%, #013007));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#006900, #013007);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#006900, #013007);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #000f02;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
button:active:not(:disabled) {
  background: #054809;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px 3px #001203, 0 1px 0 0 #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #011102;
}
button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Now you should be able to change `green` into `red`:

```
button {
    @include button(pill, red);
}
```

Or use a variable for your color:

```
$color: red;
button {
    @include button(pill, $color);
}
```

I do also think you do not need the `@import "partial";` code.

Notice that `@include button` includes a mixin from the Bourbon code which has been imported with `@import "bourbon/bourbon";` Mixins can be used to set the properties of a selector. For instance the following SCSS code:

```
@mixin button($type,$color) {
background-color: $color;
}  

$color: red;
button {
      @include button(pill, $color);
 }
```

will compile into CSS code as follows:

```
button {
  background-color: red; }
```

> How can I run the index.html page successfully?

You can use [sass.js](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/) to compile Sass in browser. Do not use this method for production code. You can install the bourdon file with [bower](http://bower.io/) by running the following command in your console:

> bower install bourbon

The preceding command installs the files in a `bower_components/bourbon` directory. Upload this directory and its content to your document root and make sure that `@import "../bower_components/bourbon";` point to this directory.